# How do I stop the screen showing when im 'alt + tab'ing through screens?

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 ALT-TAB - How to turn off previewing the window](https://superuser.com/questions/181529/windows-7-alt-tab-how-to-turn-off-previewing-the-window)

When I used to hit'alt + tab' I would get a list of screens and I could 'thumb' though them. Now, however if I stay on that screen for too long in the list the screen basically shows up. I dont want this to happen as it happens too quickly, and I want to keep the list of screens up and look through them, but Windows shows a temporary preview of the screen I am about to select.

Comment: This question has already been asked and resolved here: http://superuser.com/questions/181529/windows-7-alt-tab-how-to-turn-off-previewing-the-window

Answer (score 0):

It's painful (to get used to), but i find the Windows key + Tab, a better option in Aero than the classic alt+tab!