# Alt + Tab works differently with multiple monitors

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, alt-tab

I notice, on Windows 7, that <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> works differently if you are using one monitor than if you are using two.

With just one monitor it puts up a list and lets you cycle through the list. But with two monitors it only waits about one second with the list then brings the window up and hence cycling through the list is painful because every window keeps coming up.

Is there a way to make both single or dual monitor put up the full list and not open the window?

Answer (score 2):

Works here as expected if I keep the ALT key down ... it leaves the list up.  I can then tab again until the window I want is selected.

Comment: Yeah, I've used single and multi monitor installations of windows for ~8 years and never had any difference in alt+tabbing.

Comment: Did you do this with multiple monitors in use?

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about seeing the full version of every window as you cycle through the <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> list, there is a registry hack you can do to make it at least delay before doing that.  The full question/answer can be seen [here](https://superuser.com/a/61959/118184), but the important part is this:

> Open Registry Editor and create the following registry key:
>
> ```
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AltTab.
> ```
>
> In that key, create the following DWORD value: LivePreview_ms and set it to the delay (in milliseconds) of the first live preview.
>
> Restart Explorer to see the changes.

I don't think you can delay it permanently by setting a super high number, but it will give at least a decent amount of time for you to tab around before it starts popping windows all over the place.

Comment: I followed your link "here" and it lead to a simple way to fix this. All you have to do is Control Panel/System/Advanced System Settings/Settings and uncheck "Enable Aero Peek".

Thanks a million for your help.

Comment: Ah yes, well, completely disabling Aero Peek will turn off a few other features as well, but they may not be ones you cared about anyway.  Be sure to vote up any answers you found helpful (mine or the linked one) and accept the one here you felt best answered your question.